# Changing default parameters of Mogenerator

Tags: xcode, core-data, userscripts, mogenerator

I'm trying to make [Core Data objects inherit from my own custom class rather than NSManagedObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562006/how-can-i-make-all-core-data-objects-inherit-from-my-class-rather-than-nsmanagedo). I started using Mogenerator and noticed that it has a `--base-class` arugument which does exactly what I want.

The problem is that by default it doesn't use this parameter, and so every time I save my data model file, it sets the inherited class to `NSManagedObject`. Is there any way to add this additional parameter to the script so that it works as I want it to every time I save the `.xcdatamodel` file?

If not, is there any other way I can easily run this command from Xcode? I was thinking about creating it as a User Script. The problem is that I don't want it hardcoded to this project's files. This is an example of the command line I need to run:

```
mogenerator -m MyProject.xcdatamodeld/MyProject.xcdatamodel -O Classes --base-class MyManagedObject
```

Ideally, it should find the `.xcdatamodel` file of the current project. As I have no experience in mac development, I would appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction and tell me which commands will be the most useful to me if do indeed make this script myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Mogen readme](http://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator)

> Xmo'd: model comments that start with
>   -- are passed as args to mogenerator. This allows accessing command-line
>   options such as --base-class. (David
>   LeBer)

In Xcode, get info on the actual `.xcdatamodel` file and in the `Comments` tab enter `xmod` and then the args. That should customize Mogen as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect for this question, filing a bug on github will get Wolf's attention.  I am not sure he goes to this site.