# How to have two NSManagedObject classes with the same superclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have two classes, `Mammals` and `Fish`, which both inherit from a general superclass, `Animals`. I'd like to store all my `Mammals` and `Fish` using Core Data, so I've made them both be subclasses of NSManagedObject. So, when I want to get all my `Mammals` and `Fish`, I just execute a couple fetch requests.

My question is what to do about the `Animals` superclass.

- It's properties and methods are obviously used by the two subclasses, so should it be a NSManagedObject as well?
- If so, do `Mammals` and `Fish` even need an explicit NSManagedObject subclass because they already subclass `Animals`?
- Is this approach flawed?

Sorry if this is a super-basic question, especially if the answer is just "Yes; No." One of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562006/how-can-i-make-all-core-data-objects-inherit-from-my-class-rather-than-nsmanaged?rq=1) warned against using inheritance in the data model, hence my apprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your own decision about whether your inheritance model will tie you up in knots in the future. But in direct answer to your question your inheritance tree will look like...

```
 NSManagedObject -> Animal -> Mammals 
                           -> Fish
```

so

`@interface Animal : NSManagedObject`

and

`@interface Fish : Animal`

Just be wary as `Core-Data` does not take well to complex rearrangement if you need to upgrade your model in the future and still hang on to existing data. Not impossible, just not always easy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So, besides making future changes to the model, @shosti's warning in the linked question isn't a worry here? (It was: "Don't use inheritance in your data model if you're using the SQL backend. Because of the implementation of the SQL backend, it has horrible performance and space characteristics")

Comment: It might be depending on the final size of your model. Ive never seen that advice before. I might need to watch the video :-) But I do have several CD based projects which use inheritance to three layers and the performance isn't an issue for me over 1000's of objects. It can be useful when you describe to-relationship root class with a superclass destination e.g you might have a one->many relationship called animalsThatIEat with a destination of animal i.e. Bear -> Trout,Bunny,Squirrel,Crayfish

Comment: If performance does become a problem, note that you don't need to have the entities inherit from each other (which is what creates one giant table for all of them) in order to have a common base class for them.

Answer (score 1):

Make `Animals` subclass of `NSManagedObject`.
Make `Mammals` and `Fish` subclass of `Animals`.